# html5 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"> laravel app

Tags: html, laravel, input, capture

I'm using input capture to save photos from my Laravel app but when I view them in a preview they are squashed at the poles, does anyone know how to set the px height and width for saving the photo? A thousand thanks

```
$img = $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,gif,svg,webp|max:8000'
        ]);

$imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $request->image->move(public_path('images/images'), $imageName);

@foreach ($result as $item)
                                    <div class="dettaglio-pdca-dettaglio">
                                        <div class="dettaglio-pdca-maskgroup">
                                            <img src="/images/images/{{ $item->photo }}" alt="Foto Ticket"
                                                class="dettaglio-pdca-unsplash-jw-mgy1h-js-y zoom" />
                                        </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How are you generating and displaying the preview?

Comment: The image is going to come to you in the camera's native format.  It's up to your app to properly convert it to whatever format it needs.

Comment: ok, here is the controller code.. could you help me understand how to do it? it's something new for me..

Comment: You can do two things 1. set image hight from CSS, 2. resize the image when upload is done.

Comment: could you show me in code???

Comment: Help ???........

Comment: @Morex None of the code you've shown would change the image. View the image URL directly in your browser (outside the HTML); is it squished there? If not, perhaps your `dettaglio-pdca-unsplash-jw-mgy1h-js-y zoom` classes are doing it.